# Java String ReplaceAll and ReplaceFirst Fails at $ Symbol at Replacement Text

Tags: java, regex, replace

I wrote this code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String template = "The user has spent amount in a day";
    String pattern = "amount";
    String output = template.replaceAll(pattern, "$ 100");
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

This is what happens when I run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:713)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:813)
        at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2190)
        at demo.BugDemo.main(BugDemo.java:16)
Java Result: 1
```

I'm reading data from a file. Should I escape all `$` symbols in the file data, or is this an unnecessary process? Is there any other class or library to handle this situation?

What is the problem with having a special symbol in the replacement text (not in the regex)?

Notes:

- I don't want to check every character to escape. That's why I am asking this question.
- I'm using Java 6.

Comment: Try `\\\$`; $ I believe is a special character.

Comment: @Telthien: Not in terms of the Java language. It *is* in terms of regular expressions. Is that what you meant? (Your comment isn't clear.)

Comment: Oh, yeah, whoops. Changed the escape to `\\\$`

Comment: @Telthien: Why triple backslash though? It doesn't require escaping from Java's perspective.

Comment: It's what I found in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358010/ (also flagged as possible duplicate)

Comment: @Telthien That question asks about when pattern involves special character, totally different from my question. I have special character at my text.

Comment: @Telthien: That's PHP. Please don't assume that the rules for strings *or* regular expressions will be the same between different languages.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression *matching* pattern as its first parameter, and a regular expression *replacement* pattern as its second parameter - and `$` has a specific meaning in regular expressions (in both matching patterns and replacement patterns, although in different senses).

Just use [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead, and I suspect all your problems will go away. You should only use `replaceAll` when you genuinely *want* to match/replace via a regular expression - which I don't think you do in this case.

EDIT: As to your question:

> What is the problem with having a special symbol in the replacement text (not in the regex)?

Again, the documentation for `replaceAll` makes this clear:

> Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see `Matcher.replaceAll`. Use `Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)` to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.

So if you want to treat the *matching* pattern as a regular expression, but not the replacement, then use `Matcher.quoteReplacement`.

Comment: Well did you check the documentation for `replaceFirst`? Yes, that still uses regular expressions and replacement *patterns*. *Why* do you want to use `replaceAll` or `replaceFirst`?

Comment: I want to replace the first occurrence of "x" by "y", but not the rest. So what is the alternative?

Comment: @Jus12: That sounds like you should be asking in a new question, as it's not what this question is about. One option would be to use `indexOf` to find `x` and then `substring` and concatenation. There may be another option - and there may well be a question about this case, but it's not *this* question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Also note that the same explanation & solution applies to the `appendReplacement` method.

Comment: The problem with all that is that `String.replaceAll(regexp, replacement)` does not document that it treats the replacement String as a regexp behind the scenes. As a programmer I may be interested in using a regexp for matching, but a literal for replacement -- and if there is no corresponding hint in the API doc, I would expect just this to happen.

Comment: @ChristianGosch: To quote the documentation: "Note that backslashes (\\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll." That seems pretty clear to me. (It doesn't treat it as a regexp as such; it treats the same way that it treats the replacement string in regex replacement.)

Comment: @JonSkeet right, as I see now. I must have had a brain read buffer overflow. Its not on the very first line, but it is there. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 7):

In a replacement string, `$` is a special character: it is used to grab matched groups from the pattern you are replacing.  You can read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

To fix this, you can quote the replacement string to remove all special meaning from `$` characters:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
// ...
String output = template.replaceAll(pattern, Matcher.quoteReplacement("$ 100"));
```

Comment: Why would you do that rather than just using an API which doesn't use regular expressions?

Comment: @JonSkeet good point, if replaceAll is unnecessary your answer is better.

Comment: @kamaci the replacement text is not a regex, but it is still special.  The `$` character is special in replacement text.  Read this link for more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: @CoryKendall Should I use Matcher.quoteReplacement for replaceFirst or is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Special character `$` can be handled is simple way.
Check below example

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        String test ="Other company in $ city ";
        String test2 ="This is test company ";
        try{
            test2= test2.replaceFirst(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote("test"),  Matcher.quoteReplacement(test));
            System.out.println(test2);
            test2= test2.replaceAll(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote("test"),  Matcher.quoteReplacement(test));
            System.out.println(test2);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
This is Other company in $ city  company 
This is Other company in $ city  company
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
 String template = "The user has spent amount in a day";
 String pattern = "amount";
 String output = template.replaceAll(pattern, "\\$ 100");
 System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$` is used a symbol to specify the replacement group. You need to escape it:

```
String output = template.replaceAll(pattern, "\\$ 100");
```