# preg_match's $matches does not return any matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a file to this effect, from which I want to retrieve the name of the opening variable `$ACDF_array` using

`preg_match("/\$[^\s]*/",$line,$matches);`

```
 <?php
 $file = fopen(/folder/somefile.php, 'r');
 $line = fgets
 ($file);
 fclose($file);

 preg_match("/\$[^\s]*/",$line,$matches);  //starting with literal $ match every character until \s is reached - hopefully that is what this regex expression means

 print_r($matches);
```

somefile.php:

```
<?php $ACDF_array = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    '"No_"' => '"II00540"',
    '"Manufacturer ID"' => '"MAN-ID-GNRCABNW-02"',
    '"Description"' => '"GNR CAB NW-02-CRS"',
    '"LQ Price"' => '"1.90000000000000000000"',
    '"Retail Price Incl_ GST"' => '"14.50000000000000000000"',
    '"AvailableQty"' => '"19.00000000000000000000"',
    '"Rocklea"' => '"19.00000000000000000000"',
    '"Sydney"' => '""',
    '"Net Weight"' => '"0.10000000000000000000"',
    '"Item Category Code"' => '"GNR"',
    '"Product Group Code"' => '"CAB"',
    '"Minor Category 1"' => '"CAB-CAT5"',
    '"Minor Category 2"' => '"#"',
    '"Vendor Name"' => '""',
    '"Vendor URL"' => '""',
    '"Item URL"' => '""',
    '"Warranty"' => '""',
    '"Dimension"' => '""',
    '"Description1"' => '"2mt Cat5e Cross Network Cable. Compatible to all network ports, desktops and notebooks. Uptp 1000Mbps network speeds.<br />"',
    '"Image"' => '"https://auscompcomputers.com/uploads/image/GNR-CAB-NW-02-CRS.jpg"',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    '"No_"' => '"II00691"',
    '"Manufacturer ID"' => '"K2A"',
    '"Description"' => '"ITR KBD K2A-WHT-PS2"',
    '"LQ Price"' => '"10.00000000000000000000"',
    '"Retail Price Incl_ GST"' => '"23.00000000000000000000"',
    '"AvailableQty"' => '"86.00000000000000000000"',
    '"Rocklea"' => '"86.00000000000000000000"',
    '"Sydney"' => '""',
    '"Net Weight"' => '"0.50000000000000000000"',
    '"Item Category Code"' => '"ITR"',
    '"Product Group Code"' => '"KBD"',
    '"Minor Category 1"' => '"KBD-WIRED"',
    '"Minor Category 2"' => '"KBD-SINGLE"',
    '"Vendor Name"' => '""',
    '"Vendor URL"' => '""',
    '"Item URL"' => '""',
    '"Warranty"' => '""',
    '"Dimension"' => '""',
    '"Description1"' => '"Itron K2A Keyboard, PS2 Beige<br />"',
    '"Image"' => '"https://auscompcomputers.com/uploads/image/ITR-KBD-K2A-WHT-PS2.jpg"',
  ),

...
```

Yet the only thing printed is

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
)
```

I tested the regex match on regexr.com and it definitely matches what I expect it to match.  Am I misunderstanding how `preg_match` works?

Comment: And if you use `'/\$\S+/'`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow, that worked!  You're welcome to post as answer and I can accept.

Comment: You need to use single quotes around your regex, or escape the backslash in it i.e. `"/\\$[^\s]*/"`

Comment: Actually, a dupe of [Regex failing when pattern involves dollar sign ($)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358010/regex-failing-when-pattern-involves-dollar-sign)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Do I get penalized/banned if you flag it as dupe?  I mean, I had no idea it was this issue at all, and therefore it would have been impossible for me relate it to the duplicate question before I knew the answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks - I'll add that to my dupes list

Comment: No idea, please check at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/